# Pasting numbers with comma as thousand separator from business objects to excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste, business-objects, cell-formatting

When doing Edit -> Copy all from BOBJ XI 3.1 report to excel, numbers with comma as thousand separator are being treated as text in Excel.

Has anyone come across this issue?

**UPDATE**: Don't know if this sample of data is any useful, but here it is:

18,734.04
12,489.36
0.00
0.00
1,673.73
1,115.82

All the numbers greater that 999.00, i.e. with comma as a thousand separator, are getting formatted as "General" with small green triangle next to them offering several option of how to treat the value in the cell.

Comment: You can convert text to number use VALUE, e.g.: `=VALUE("1,234,567.89")`

Comment: There should be some sort of setting for that or some third factor as it used to work fine, and then all of a sudden changed for one of my colleges. I.e. I know how to convert it back to numbers in Excel, I just want them to be passed as numbers initially without any additional actions.

Comment: Sample data would be useful for us to test.

Comment: Not sure if it's any helpful, but please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces when copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Although I already did that before posting the question.

Comment: i mentioned it because I could not replicate the issue unless i captured spaces while copying. is the format of the recipient cells set to `numeric` or at least not `text`?